# json string is not properly shown in android device

Tags: string, parsing, json

i am facing a issue on getting JObject, my app is working in emulator and it is not working in device. because the string is not properly converting to JObject.

```
E/JSON 1111﹕ parsing data {"success":1,"projects":[{"thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","duration":"3 mins","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","keywords":"law,white sheet,pen,pencil,mini bulbs,","materials":"pen,pencil,ball,worksheet","description":"about the law bla bla","subject":"science","target":"k2","created_at":"2015-08-14 14:24:54","pid":"1","rating":"4","procedure":"procedure about this project"},{"thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","duration":"3 mins","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","keywords":"pen,pencil,color pencil,chart,sticks","materials":"pen,pencil,color pencil,chart,sticks,etc","description":"about description of the project","subject":"science","target":"k3","created_at":"2015-08-14 14:25:16",
"pid":"2","rating":"3","procedure":"about description of the procedure"},{"thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","duration":"5 mins","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","keywords":"pen,pencil,wire,chart,sticks","materials":"pen,pencil,color pencil,chart,sticks,eraser","description":"about description of the project","subject":"english","target":"k4","created_at":"2015-08-14 14:25:21",
....
"pid":"8","rating":"3","procedure":"about description of the procedure"}]}


the above is the output of the jsonObject, the below is the correct result showing in emulator

{"projects":[{"pid":"1","target":"k2","subject":"science","description":"about the law bla bla","duration":"3 mins","materials":"pen,pencil,ball,worksheet","procedure":"procedure about this project","keywords":"law,white sheet,pen,pencil,mini bulbs,","thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","rating":"4","created_at":"2015-08-14 14:24:54","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pid":"2","target":"k3","subject":"science","description":"about description of the project","duration":"3 mins","materials":"pen,pencil,color pencil,chart,sticks,etc","procedure":"about description of the procedure","keywords":"pen,pencil,color pencil,chart,sticks","thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","rating":"3","created_at":"2015-08-14 14:25:16","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},
...
{"pid":"8","target":"k3","subject":"english","description":"to learn english tenses","duration":"3 mins","materials":"white sheet,pen,pencil,eraser","procedure":"about description of the procedure","keywords":"english,grammer,tenses","thumbimg":"http:\/\/spvdigi.com\/diyaphp\/images\/lab.png","rating":"3","created_at":"2015-08-18 06:45:28","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}


this is my jsonparse class code:


public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
static String jboolean = "0";
static JSONArray jarr =null;


// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
List<NameValuePair> params) {

// Making HTTP request
try {

// check for request method
if(method == "POST"){
// request method is POST
// defaultHttpClient
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000 + 12000);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
httpPost.setParams(httpParameters);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();

}else if(method == "GET"){
// request method is GET
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
url += "?" + paramString;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

is = httpEntity.getContent();

}


} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("Buffer 11", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("Buffer 22", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("Buffer 33", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
json = sb.toString();
//Log.e("JSON 1111 ", "parsing data " + json.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Buffer Error????", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
jObj = new JSONObject(json);

Log.e("JSON 1111 ", "parsing data " + jObj.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
Log.e("JSON Parser44", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

return jObj;

/// This JObj is not properly getting the json string???
// return JSON String
}
}
```

Is there any issues on the above code?   i am facing a issue on getting JObject, my app is working in emulator and it is not working in device. because the string is not properly converting to JObject.

Comment: Your problem seems to be in fetching the JSON string from the Web API, can you just make your question more clear?

Comment: hai, the issue is JSON String showing perfectly in emulator and run the app , when i run the same on device it is not loading the screen shows blank and the jObj is not properly returning, the last part of the string jumps to the top the string example half of the content ID 8 is sitting before content ID 1, see the first four lines of Log. thanks